# Subdomain forwarding to an offsite url?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

How would I redirect subdomain.domain.com to display targetdomain.com without altering the URL?  So that subdomain.domain.com/graph.php would actually display targetdomain.com/graph.php?

I know it's something to do with mod_rewrite and .htaccess - I just can't get it working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. You need to enable and use Apache mod_proxy on your Apache config. See this link: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html